# WPF + XAML + DataGrid + Powershell 2.0

Tags: wpf, xaml, powershell, datagrid

I'm trying to put a data grid in a WPF. Simple enough in Powershell.. But when i run the code in Powershell 2.0, it can't find gives me errors.

Sample code:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

$xaml = [xml] @"
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Title="My window" Height="300" Width="300">
<DockPanel>
    <Button x:Name="okButton" Content="OK" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" />
    <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
</DockPanel>
</Window>
"@

$reader = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml
$form = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)

$okButton = $form.FindName("okButton")

$okButton.add_Click({ $form.Close() })

$form.WindowStartupLocation = "CenterScreen"
$form.ShowDialog();
```

If you remove this line, everything work fine:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
```

Anyone has any suggestions?

Error i get in Powershell 2.0:

> Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "The tag 'DataGrid'
>   does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx
>   /2006/xaml/presentation'. Line '0' Position '0'." At line:15 char:42
>   + $form = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load <<<< ($reader)
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Comment: What exact errors do you receive? 2 possible options from top of my head: different .net version, or additional references load required, or both.

Comment: See the updated question with the error..

Comment: Works fine in PS 4.0, .NET 4.5. What version of .NET do you have?

Comment: I know it does.. The question asks why doesn't it work in PS 2.0.. I have an environment that is PS 2.0 only.. :/

Comment: No need to get all excited ;) All I was trying to say was, that the error seems specific to version 2 of PowerShell. I can also confirm that version of .NET does not mater.

Comment: Thanks for confirming 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default PowerShell 2.0 will use .NET framework 2.0. There is no DataGrid in .NET v 2.0. Type :

```
[environment]::Version
```

If you get this, or something else starting with 2...

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
2      0      50727  7905
```

Your PowerShell session is using NET 2.0. [How to "Enable .Net 4.0 access from PowerShell V2"?](http://learn-powershell.net/2012/01/10/enable-net-4-0-access-from-powershell-v2/)

EDIT:

To fix this on PS 2.0 ....

Create files C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe.config  and C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell_ise.exe.config with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<configuration> 
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />    
    </startup> 
</configuration>
```

After this, you can load .NET 4 run-times:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WPF\PresentationFramework.dll"
```

assuming you have .NET 4 loaded.

Comment: Great answer to why it's not working.. But why am i able to use: `New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView` in `System.Windows.Forms` ?

Comment: System.Windows.Forms and PresentationFramework are two very different animals. Your code loads `System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid`.

Comment: and i'm assuming i can't load `System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid` in Powershell 2.0.. right? :'(

Comment: Yes, that's correct. To fix it you have to have .NET 4 and fix PS 2 to be able to use it.